# How to properly return Java object from REST service in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, rule-engine

I have a REST method that accepts a Java object, does some calculations through a rules engine and return another Java object.

The rule engine works fine and returns back Java object (my Java class is named Tier)

And in the REST method, I successfully retrieve the output from rules engine as a Tier object like this:

```java
for (FactHandle fh : factHandlesTier) {
    t = (Tier) ((DefaultFactHandle) fh).getObject();        
}
```

I can check that my object t of type Tier indeed receives data when I print it:

```
System.out.println("Tier Category ===> " + t.getCategory() + " Tier Total ===> "
 + t.getTotal());
```

I get this output `Tier Output ===> 2 Tier Total ===> 0.15000000000000002`

But my problem is, when it comes to the return statement in my REST method, the returned object seems to be initialized and somehow loses data that came from rules engine.
This is output from my REST method via the browser: `{"category":0,"id":0,"quantity":0,"total":0.0,"value":0.0}`

Here is my Tier Java class:

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package za.co.ganizani.sponsorship.model.rules;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Tier implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private double value;
    private int quantity;
    private double total;
    private int category;
    private String type;

    public Tier() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(int category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

And here's my REST method:

```
    @GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) 
@Path("/calculate")
@ApiOperation(value="/calculate", notes="Calulate Sponsorship values")
public static Tier CalculateSponsorship(Event e) { 

    ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    ksession.insert(e);
    //insert categories in StatefulKnowledgeSession
    for(int a = 0; a < categoryList.size(); a++){
         ksession.insert(categoryList.get(a));
    }

    //insert tiers in StatefulKnowledgeSession
    for(int b = 0; b < tierList.size(); b++){
        ksession.insert(tierList.get(b));
    }

    ksession.fireAllRules();

    //retrieve rules engine outputs
    Collection<FactHandle> factHandlesTier;
    factHandlesTier = ksession.getFactHandles(new ClassObjectFilter(Tier.class));
    Tier t = new Tier();

    for (FactHandle fh : factHandlesTier) {
        t = (Tier) ((DefaultFactHandle) fh).getObject();
    }


    ksession.dispose();
    System.out.println("Tier Category ===> " + t.getCategory() + " Tier Total ===> " + t.getTotal());
    //t.setCategory(333);
    return t;    
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't know Drools, but: 1) What is purpose of calling `new Tier()` if you're just going to replace it in the loop? 2) What if collection has more than one fact? You're only retaining the last one, is that really what you want? 3) Aren't you supposed to call `t = (Tier) ksession.getObject(fh)` instead of doing that cast to `DefaultFactHandle`?

Comment: @ Andreas I tried what you suggested: t = (Tier) ksession.getObject(fh) but I get the same result. If the collection has more than one fact, I am going to store all the facts in an ArrayList, then in a Tier array –

Comment: @Andreas and if I don't do `Tier t = new Tier()` I get an error saying the object needs to be initialized

Comment: Its better create a parameterized constructor in `Tier` class and initialize before returns it better.